# Returning errors as with Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

It seems as if once I use Group By in my query I begin returning errors in my where clause.

```
SELect Rtrim(riders.firstName)||' '||rtrim(riders.lastname) AS Rider_Name, teams.teamname, Rtrim(agents.firstName)||' '||rtrim(agents.lastname) AS Agent_Name
FROM Riders, teams, agents, participation, races
Where teams.teamID = riders.teamID
and agents.agentID = riders.agentID
and participation.riderID = riders.riderid
and races.raceid = participation.raceid
and races.RaceDate Between '01-Apr-2008' and '30-Apr-2008'
```

That returns the results I need, but I need to eliminate any duplicates so i've done

```
Group BY Rtrim(riders.firstName)||' '||rtrim(riders.lastname)
```

and

```
Group BY participation.riderID
```

and

```
Group By rider.riderID
```

and those were my best guesses.
here is the full code.

```
SQL> SELect Rtrim(riders.firstName)||' '||rtrim(riders.lastname) AS Rider_Name,
teams.teamname, Rtrim(agents.firstName)||' '||rtrim(agents.lastname) AS Agent_Na
me
  2  FROM Riders, teams, agents, participation, races
  3  Where teams.teamID = riders.teamID
  4  and agents.agentID = riders.agentID
  5  and participation.riderID = riders.riderid
  6  and races.raceid = participation.raceid
  7  and races.RaceDate Between '01-Apr-2008' and '30-Apr-2008'
  8  Group BY participation.riderid
  9  ;
SELect Rtrim(riders.firstName)||' '||rtrim(riders.lastname) AS Rider_Name, teams
.teamname, Rtrim(agents.firstName)||' '||rtrim(agents.lastname) AS Agent_Name
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: When you use group by, you need an aggregate such as sum, count, etc.  If you just want to eliminate dupes, use select distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to eliminate *exact* duplicate rows, you can just use `select distinct`:

```
SELect DISTINCT Rtrim(riders.firstName)||' '||rtrim(riders.lastname) AS Rider_Name,
       teams.teamname, Rtrim(agents.firstName)||' '||rtrim(agents.lastname) AS Agent_Name
```

Then don't use the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Group By rider.riderID

you just need to add rider.riderID into the fields list

FWIW group by is faster than distinct

Comment: In Oracle, you can only use group by by if there is an aggregate in the select clause.

Comment: The OP has got "races" in the table list so could add in count(races.id)
It's a while since I've worked on Oracle and didn't realise that was the database.

Comment: The questioner tagged the question as oracle.  That comes under the category of paying attention.  That being the case, I'm actually surprised that I noticed.

Comment: Hangin' my head with newbie shame :)